# Show files (Images) in a Java-application

Tags: java, image, list, jpeg, show

I have a list of JPEG-files (List photos) and I want them to be opened by Windows's default viewer for this extension, how do I do that?

Comment: Unless you show us what you have tried, no one's going to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `java.awt.Desktop` class for this:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("image.jpg"));
```

This will open the image using the default application for opening JPG files on your computer.